# Design pattern to add a new class

Tags: design-patterns

I have two classes, Student and Teacher, Student has one concrete method: takeCourse; Teacher has one concrete method: teachCourse.

Now I want to add a new Class, GradStudent, which can take course, like Student, and also can teach course, like Teacher. Which pattern is the easiest way to implement this new class ? Adapter, Composite, Delegate .... ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question should be what is the best way to model this for which the answer would be "the way it makes sense in the real world" i.e. A Grad student can also teach and take course ;-)

Do not try to relate everything to the design patterns. Stick to the basic principle that we learnt in school "Classes model real world objects", "Keep the model close to the real world"

```
interface CanTeach
{
void teachCource();
}

class Teacher implements CanTeach {...}

class Student 
{
void takeCourse(...);
}

class GradStudent extends Student implements CanTeach
{
...
}
```

Comment: I did this way. Is it right ? Class GradStudent {Student student; Teacher teacher; public void takeCourse(){student.takeCourse();}...}

Comment: No GradStudent should extend from Student. Look at my code carefully

Comment: Your solution has a problem, it must rewrite teachCourse logic. It can't use the existing logic defined in Teacher.

Comment: That is the tradeoff which I am ok with to keep things real. Implementation inheritance is bad. You can either redefine the logic or you can have a class "BasicTeachable implements CanTeach" and then delegate teachCourse() method in Teacher and GradStudent to BasicTeacheable.teachCourse(). Which choice you choose is subjective driven by your business context.